# Composer: can't download dependency under Windows Azure

Tags: json, azure, composer-php

I have such a composer.json file:

```
 1   {
 2       "require": {
 3           "microsoft/windowsazure": "*"
 4       },          
 5       "repositories": [
 6           {
 7               "type": "pear",
 8               "url": "http://pear.php.net"
 9           }
 10       ],
 11       "minimum-stability": "dev"
 12   }
```

But when I write these codes on my compiler like dreamweaver, it gives a syntax error on the 2nd row.

I have to install my `composer.phar` (which is on the same root with `composer.json`) by entering

```
php /d/website/public_html/website/composer.phar install
```

command on Git, but it gives such an error:

> microsoft/windowsazure v0.4.0 requires `pear-pear/http_request2` * -> no
>   matching package found

Does the problem cause from that syntax error?

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Try this https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2779#issuecomment-36627424

Comment: Thank you Piotr. I'm gonna try now.

Comment: Thank you for your advise Piotr, but actually I couldn't understand what to implement and modify from this website. :)

Comment: Okay, Piotr. Sorry. Now I got it. I will try it. :)

Comment: @PiotrOlaszewski, please consider posting this as an answer so that the OP can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

as stof mentioned on github https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2779#issuecomment-36627424 , add azure's requirement replacement in the root composer.json, so the composer.json will look like this

```
{
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "pear",
        "url": "http://pear.php.net"
    }
],
"require": {
    "pear-pear.php.net/mail_mime" : "*",
    "pear-pear.php.net/http_request2" : "*",
    "pear-pear.php.net/mail_mimedecode" : "*",
    "microsoft/windowsazure": "*"
}
}
```